# Yii DataProvider with two tables

Tags: yii, criteria, dataprovider

I have two tables

```
User:
id | name | gender(boolean)

Gender:
gender_id (boolean) | gender_name (text)
```

I want to display the text representation of gender through DataProvider

```
UserController:
public function actionIndex()
{           
  $crt = new CDbCriteria();
  $crt->alias = 'so';
  $crt->select = 'so.id, so.name, so.gender, fl.Gender_name';   
  $crt->join = " left join " . Gender::model()->tableName() . " as fl on fl.Gender_id = so.Gender"; 

  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array('criteria' => $crt));
  $this->render('index',array(dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
}
```

As a result, I can not pass through dataProvider table `gender`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can beter create a [relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) in the models. This way you dont have to use the criteria, and the value canbe accessed through `$model->gender->gender_name` for example

Comment: I don't think it should be in a db table. A custom method on the model would be enough. Something like getGenderText()